# run ubuntu 18.04 as OS for android phone

Tags: 18.04, android

I'm talking about the OS made for PC. what would happened if I install it on android phone? will it figure out the hardware or is it a guarantee way to kill a phone?

checking if anyone tried before I sacrifice my old phone.
this is not a duplicate with ubuntu touch or supported devices! this sticking a laptop OS to phone without source customization

Comment: Ask yourself two questions: What processor does my phone have? Does Ubuntu make a version for that processor?

Comment: Note that Canonical ended development of Ubuntu Touch and any work on phones in April 2017.

Comment: Short answer is no, and it's not at all sensible. You can perhaps run it in a chroot _on top_ of Android, as is done with the Samsung Dex for example, but you cannot run it instead of Android.

Answer (score 0):

18.04 will never work for there is no 18.04 version of Ubuntu Touch. Canonical ended development of Ubuntu Touch and any work on phones in April 2017.

Comment: I am aware of that, I'm not talking about Ubuntu touch. I remembered few years back I managed to install windows 95 on my phone as a POC and it worked. it did require additional work, and it wasn't easy to use, but hey.. it worked.. 

I wonder if anyone tried ubuntu 18.04 (laptop version) on a phone or tablet.. or fridge..